# What min/max widths should I be using for my media queries?

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I'm m coding my first responsive site and have decided to use 3 different CSS files that will use media queries. I was just wondering what is the typical width of the screen for a smart-phone, tablet and monitor? Are there typical values that coders use? Any other tips would be greatly appreciated! Regards

Comment: Really depends on your audience, but there are several good questions already on StackOverflow regarding the topic and a Google search will yield rewards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to be very helpful in getting a sense of standard, baseline media queries for various devices. Bear in mind that screen resolutions are all over the map these days, no matter the device size, and you should strive for general fluidity even beyond these basic breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks, its tough doing it for the first time!

Comment: Oh I've been there! :)

Comment: Oh, and make sure you're using a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) as well in conjunction with the media queries!